# Detect correct file extension for OpenXmls?

Tags: ms-office, openxml

If we have been provided only the XMLs of the document (in input stream, unzipped manner, or in a byte array), can we detect the file extension via parsing XMLs? My motive is to know what particular node in which XML determines that this is DOCX, PPTX, or XLSX file?

Answer (score 0):

I unzipped the documents and tried to dig and found this -

In `\docProps\app.xml`, application node defines it - 
 
`<Application>Microsoft Excel</Application>` for Excel, 
`<Application>Microsoft Office PowerPoint</Application>` for PowerPoint, and 
`<Application>Microsoft Office Word</Application>` for Word.